# SQLAlchemy, Flask, ошибка записи в postgres

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Есть две таблицы, связанные между собой Users и Profiles. Ссылка на БД правильная, связь есть.

```
class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    psw = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'users {self.id}'


class Profiles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    age = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'users {self.id}
```

В функции происходит условие Post-запроса и должна идти запись в бд(postgres), но по какой-то причине этого не происходит

```
@app.route('/registarion', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def registration():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hash_psw = generate_password_hash(form.psw.data)
        try:
            u = Users(form.email.data, hash_psw)
            db.session.add(u)
            p = Profiles(form.name.data, form.surname.data, form.age.data,
                         u.id)
            db.session.add(p)
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
            print('Ошибка добавления в БД')
    return render_template('registration.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я индивид, и не прописал в самой форме метод POST!!!